# Can not close serial port using boost asio

Tags: c++, qt, boost, serial-port

I am having an issue that it seems someone else has encountered but appears to be not asked here.  I have a *very* simple application that right now just opens and closes a serial port using boost asio (just trying to do some simple debugging right now before building a larger application. The calls reside in a qt based gui.  The serial communication right now is set up in the window constructor:

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(getData()));
    timer->start(1000);

    std::string comm = "/dev/ttyUSB0";

    boost::asio::io_service io;
    port = std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::serial_port>(new   boost::asio::serial_port(io, comm));
    std::cout << "Port has been successfully opened..." << std::endl;

    boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate baud(19200);

    port->set_option(baud);
    std::cout << "Baud rate set to 19200..." << std::endl;



    getData();
}
```

`getData` will contain calls to the serial port at regular intervals, but right now it just makes a request to populate a time stamp on the gui with the current time.

The port is closed in the destructor

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    if (port->is_open()) port->close();
    delete ui;

}
```

When the gui is closed, the destructor is called, but the system just hangs at the port closing.  It appears that it is getting stuck in boost's `posix_mutex.hpp` `lock` method.

I have seen another post about this (https://cpc110.blogspot.com/2017/03/boost-asio-can-not-close-serial-port.html), but it appears that there is no answer to that one.  Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

I am using boost 1.58 and Qt 5.8 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably (I'm pretty new to boost::asio myself) that your io_service is already destructed. Try to make it a member of your MainWindow class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - can you expand on this?  Why would it be already destructed?  Since it is referenced by a shared_ptr, I would expect the service to not be destroyed until after delete ui.

Comment: The service[boost::asio::io_service io;] is created on the stack and will be destroyed at the completion of the MainWindow constructor. Also, Qt has its own QSerialPort class, any reason you are not using that?